# "make a big difference to your English" vs. "make a big difference in your English"

Tags: prepositions

I understand [the meaning of "make a (big) difference"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/make-a-big-difference), I am a bit confused about the usage of the preposition though.

[Ngram Viewer shows that both are common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=make%20a%20big%20difference%20to%2C%20make%20a%20big%20difference%20in&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmake%20a%20big%20difference%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmake%20a%20big%20difference%20in%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cmake%20a%20big%20difference%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmake%20a%20big%20difference%20in%3B%2Cc0)

[image]

[From a tutorial (transcript)](https://youtu.be/Vu6UVwkUgzc?list=PLD6t6ckHsrubLp8Ia8duzu5fN4riM2-Bl&t=14)

> When you speak English, do other people find it difficult to
>   understand what you’re saying? If so, you might not be using stress
>   correctly. Pronouncing words with the correct stress can 
>   **make a big difference to** your English ...

While her pronunciation sounds like

> ... **make a big difference in** your English ...

Obviously, the speaker is trying to say that pronouncing words with the correct stress can make your English better.

To convey that idea, should I use "in" or "to" there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ngram is useless here because the phrases have different meanings.

> Of course it makes a difference to my happiness if my sister marries that lunatic.

Here the effect being discussed is emotional.

> Of course it makes a difference in the prognosis whether the biopsy shows cancer or not.

Here the effect being discussed is non-emotional.

In the question you asked, the effect desired is non-emotional and calls for "difference in."

Ngram is a great tool, but it does not distinguish between different meanings.